# Ubuntu 15.10 running slower than exepcted?

Tags: 15.10

Not sure why its running so slow was wondering if anyone had some input on the matter currently the system is being ran on a i3 m370 2.4quad with 5.5gigs of ram and a swap of 5gig maybe I just expected too much?

Comment: Since you are new, I just want to let you know that the answer section is not a place to add additional info. Additional info should be added to the question itself using the edit link below the question. For discussions you can use the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the proprietary drivers for your GPU. You may also try Lubuntu or Xubuntu for the best performance. I cannot give you much more advice from your question, maybe edit it with more specific content?

Answer (score 0):

Well not totally sure what more information you would really want if you gave me some idea I could try and provide it. I will also see what kind of drivers I can locate for this device while I am at it. I mean its not a horrible kind of slow but it takes a solid 20 to 30 seconds to load an application firefox takes even longer. :P I guess I just expected it to use less resources than windows so I expected it to run faster though it isn't running horrible.